# Adding a rectangle to a quiver plot

Tags: matplotlib

I have a data with velocity vectors `(U,V)` at different locations `(X,Y)`.  I know to plot the quiver plot using the data.

```
plt.quiver(data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,3],data[:,4])
```

In the quiver plot, I need to show a rectangular area.

I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

A Rectangle in matplotlib can be plotted using [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle( (x, y), width, height, ...)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle).

For example, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

# generate some data
data = np.random.rand(10,5)
# define a rectangle
# patches.Rectangle( (x, y), width, height, ...)
rectangle = patches.Rectangle( (0.2, 0.3), 0.5, 0.4, alpha=0.5)
ax = plt.gca()
# add the rectangle to the axes
ax.add_patch(rectangle)
# plot the quiver plot
plt.quiver(data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,2]*5,data[:,3]*5, data[:,4])

plt.show()
```

[image]